# Biting butter and crumbs

Tags: popular-refrains, lyrics

In a song by The Last Shadow Puppets there is this line:
"Can't you see
I'm the ghost in the wrong coat
Biting butter and crumbs"

Is the "Biting butter and crumbs" an actual saying, or just a metaphor by the writer?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, Google Books searches for "biting butter and crumbs," "bite butter and crumbs," "bites butter and crumbs," and "bit butter and crumbs" produce zero matches. It seems fair to conclude that the phrase is not an established idiom in English.

Whether the phrase is intended literally (*the singer is in fact a ghost, and is eating or trying to eat butter and crumbs*) or metaphorically (*the singer is sad since you left him, and all that remains of the feast that life, with you, once was are fragmentary memories*) is a question of lyrical interpretation, not English usage.